# iPhone safari web app floating div

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, web-applications, safari

Am wondering how to achieve a floating div in iPhone Safari. position:fixed does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ahh!** I've been waiting for someone to ask this!

This is **[THE Tutorial](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)** on how to achieve `position: fixed` in **Mobile Safari**.